# Replace every '$' in a Long String with a number from 1 to 165 confusion?

Tags: python, function, loops, methods

My goal:
I have a very long str which which looks like this:

```
longStr = '<option value = $>A/D/S (Pre-ADST)</option><option value = $>Aiwa</option><option value = $>Alphard Audio</option><option value = $>Alphasonik</option><option value = $>Alpine</option><option value = $>Altec Lansing</option><option value = $>Alumapro</option><option value = $>American Bass</option><option value = $>American HiFi</option>........'
```

And so on..
It is html for selections of audio brands and the 'option value' is supposed to take a number from 1 to whatever so ultimately it ends look like:

```
longStr = '<option value = "1">A/D/S (Pre-ADST)</option><option value = "2">Aiwa</option><option value = "3">Alphard Audio</option><option value = "4">Alphasonik</option><option value = "5">Alpine</option><option value = "6">Altec Lansing</option><option value = "7">Alumapro</option><option value = "9">American Bass</option><option value = "10">American HiFi</option>........'
```

Again, so on and so forth.

So I started by replacing all the "#"'s with a $ so that I could the somehow loop through the string again now replacing each $ with a number from 1 -165 (e.g. loop through until the first $ and replace it with a "1", continue until the next '$' and replace it with a "2" and so on. I've tried everything yet I can't tackle the correct outcome. Any help would be appreciated!! Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string on "$" and fill in the values as you iterate through the list. Then combine with `str.join`

```
longStr = '<option value = $>A/D/S (Pre-ADST)</option><option value = $>Aiwa</option><option value = $>Alphard Audio</option><option value = $>Alphasonik</option><option value = $>Alpine</option><option value = $>Altec Lansing</option><option value = $>Alumapro</option><option value = $>American Bass</option><option value = $>American HiFi</option>........'

x = ''.join(f'{v}"{i+1}"' for i, v in enumerate(longStr.split('$')))
print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alec's answer is ideal, however if you want a much more simple answer:

You can use a for loop and go through each single character in the string, and check whether it is "$". Then, you can replace that using `str.replace(old,new,count)`.

Here is the code implementation:

```
longStr = '<option value = $>A/D/S (Pre-ADST)</option><option value = $>Aiwa</option><option value = $>Alphard Audio</option><option value = $>Alphasonik</option><option value = $>Alpine</option><option value = $>Altec Lansing</option><option value = $>Alumapro</option><option value = $>American Bass</option><option value = $>American HiFi</option>........'
count = 0
for i in longStr:
    if i == "$":
        count += 1
        replace = "\""+ str(count) + "\""
        longStr = longStr.replace('$',str(count),1)
print(longStr)
```

Sorry made a mistake earlier.

Comment: I saw that, and I appreciate it!! your solution works perfectly as well.